# Code igniter Destroys session in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have built a chat website using code igniter and launched it online. After a few days I get feedback that users get instantly logged out after posting 1-2 messages on the chat. The problems were reported with chrome and IE browsers. After looking into it deeper I found out that after a few JavaScript requests it just changes session cookie and logs the person out, but I couldn't find a way to fix this problem.

Can someone take a look at this to see whats wrong? or maybe you guys already know about this problem? I dont personally have this problem when i log in from my computer, everything works fine. But i received some short clips which show otherwise.

http://free-speak.com

Comment: what value is set in config file for session timeout variable ?

Comment: Ok. Check this and try for user agent.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493871/codeigniter-sessions-keep-getting-destroyed?noredirect=1#comment50964609_31493871

Answer (score 0):

This is expiry time problem. Check config.php file. Give time conflict with browser time hosted server time.

**Solution:**

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 86400;//1 day 86400 | default 7200 (2 hrs)

$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;//default FALSE

$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;

$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```