# CodeIgniter sessions keep getting destroyed

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm working on an older application which uses CodeIgniter 2.1.3. During development it runs on a vhost, accessible at http://vhostname/app (which equals xampp/htdocs/project/app).

I copied the live system 1:1 to my development system (with database and everything).

The system uses sessions to store temp data for visitors (e.g. cart). My problem: on my development env the session is destroyed on every refresh. After some testing I found at that it's happening in the `system/core/Sessions.php`:

```
        // encryption was not used, so we need to check the md5 hash
        $hash    = substr($session, strlen($session)-32); // get last 32 chars
        $session = substr($session, 0, strlen($session)-32);

        // Does the md5 hash match?  This is to prevent manipulation of session data in userspace
        if ($hash !==  md5($session.$this->encryption_key))
        {
            log_message('error', 'The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt.');
            $this->sess_destroy();
            return FALSE;
        }
```

But I have absolutely no idea why this is happening and run out of ideas slowly.

The only mentionable difference between live and dev system:

- On the live system the application is embedded via an iframe to a WordPress installation. Hence the URL is not http://vhost/app but http://projectname.com

Update:
At least I've just found the reason why the hash doesn't match the encryption key. I'm including the `wp-head.php` from WordPress to get access to WordPress functions. But it seems that my sessions "get corrupted" at this point - without the include the session stays alive.

Update 2:
Okay, I think I'm getting closer. I tried to compare the session cookies, one with the wordpress included version and one without. There's actually a big difference:

The cookie with WordPress included:

```
a:6:{s:10:\"session_id\";s:32:\"8e3b975d0b30f6b229f475b2f03947a0\";s:10:\"ip_address\";s:9:\"127.0.0.1\";s:10:\"user_agent\";[...]
```

Without WordPress:

```
a:6:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"7451cd27e1b45d2c7b8a042ed6b2bf9e";s:10:"ip_address";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:10:"user_agent";[...]
```

Where does these quotation marks come from?

Thanks!

Comment: can you let me know the session setting in config file also what browser you are using ?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/nehalist/5df5f01e4a009fcebaf1

Answer (score 0):

Check your session setting in config file

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
```

If sess_match_useragent set as true. Then make it false and try.

As codeigniter check each time for useragent and return its value like

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0a1) Gecko/20120206 Firefox/13.0a1
```

OR

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0a1)
```

and check with cookie. Some time its trim user_agent and save in cookie but compare with full return value which cause this issue.

If you are using database for saving session in codeingiter

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
enter code here
```

then in CI_session table increase user_agent column length.

Comment: Changing session config didn't change anything at all. I've fixed it temporarily by adding `stripslashes` to the `sess_read` function, but modifying the core shouldn't be the right solution I guess...

Comment: did you change  $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;  to FALSE ?
don't change core library If you want any change then extend library